# Iterate thought javascript object to see if it has a certain value

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to figure out the best way to interate through a javascript object to see if one of the keys is set to a certain value.  I understand I can do a foreach loop but I feel like there is an easier way.

```
var myObject =  {
    a: false,
    b: false,
    c: false,
    x: false
}
```

Id like a quick way to return a true if at least one of those values is set to true, and false if all are false.

Comment: You have to loop.. `for (var key in myObject) { if (myObject[key] === true) return true; } return false;`

Comment: Sometimes the simple answer is the best answer

Comment: There is no way that doesn't involve some code somewhere doing a loop over all the keys.

Comment: If you used an array, you could use the indexOf() function, but as for objects, use a loop. A loop is not a big deal nor process intensive. If needed in multiple places, create a method that accepts an object (or prototype a new object method) and searches for the value amd returns the key if found.

Answer (score 4):

You have to iterate, but you can do something like this

```
var hasTrue = Object.keys(myObject).some(function(key) {
    return myObject[key];
});
```

this uses [`Array.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and stops as soon as a `true` value is encountered.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/7bur1yqv/)

Answer (score 0):

To return the `key` that has `yourValue` as its value, just do:

```
var yourValue = true;

var key = Object.keys(myObject).filter(function (i) {
    return myObject[i] === yourValue;
})[0];
```

It will return `undefined` if no key found.

If you dont need the `key` and you only need to know if the value is in your object, you can just use the `some` method:

```
var hasValue = Object.keys(myObject).some(function (i) {
    return myObject[i] === yourValue;
});
```

Comment: which is the same as for (var i in myObject) {...}

Comment: not really, `Object.keys` will not seek for keys into inherited prototypes

Answer (score 0):

```
var any_true = false;
JSON.stringify(myObject, function(key, value) { 
    if (value === true) any_true = true; 
});
```

This uses the callback feature of `JSON.stringify`. It has the advantage that it finds **any** true value, even in nested objects.